# Is there a Chromeless player solution for videos hosted elsewhere besides Youtube?

Tags: javascript, flash, flv, youtube-api, swfobject

I am looking for the abilities that Youtube's Chromeless player has to offer but for non-Youtube hosted videos such as Metacafe, Vimeo, Viddler, etc. Abilities I will need are :

- Mute/Unmute (toggle)
- Volume
- Loop
- Resize video dimensions
- Current play back position
- Load bar

Can I use Chromeless player for videos hosted on other sites besides Youtube?
If not, is there a solution out there?
If not, what languages/APIs would I need use and know to create such an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to use the Flash built-in video component, which lets you change the color and they offer an "invisible" (chromless?) version that only shows up on the rollover.

JW Player is very popular, and there is also the Strobe Media Player (www.osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html).

You can use the OSMF (open source media framework) but this uses flash 10.1, sample code would be:

```
package

{

import flash.display.Sprite;

import org.osmf.containers.MediaContainer;

import org.osmf.elements.VideoElement;

import org.osmf.events.LoaderEvent;

import org.osmf.media.MediaPlayer;

import org.osmf.media.URLResource;

import org.osmf.net.NetLoader;

public class BasicOSMFProgressive extends Sprite

{

private const PROGRESSIVE:String = "http://localhost/video.mp4";

private var _display:MediaContainer;

private var _player:MediaPlayer;

private var _netLoader:NetLoader;

public function BasicOSMFProgressive()

{

_netLoader = new NetLoader();

_netLoader.addEventListener( LoaderEvent.LOAD_STATE_CHANGE, onLoaderStateChange );

var media:VideoElement = new VideoElement( new URLResource( PROGRESSIVE ), _netLoader );

_player = new MediaPlayer( media );

_display = new MediaContainer();

_display.addMediaElement( media );

addChild( _display );

}

private function onLoaderStateChange( e:LoaderEvent ) :void

{

trace( "MediaElement is: " + e.newState );

}

}

}
```

Comment: How do I manipulate another sites video player skin to be transparent. Just so you know, I do not want to work with Youtube if that is what you were referring to when you said "The easiest option is to use the Flash built-in video component, which lets you change the color and they offer an "invisible" (chromless?) version that only shows up on the rollover." I want to work with other sites that offer embedding of their videos.

Comment: What I want to do is to remove their GUI controls (aka skin) and replace them with my own. Is this really possible with JW Player? Or does one have to host the videos on their own server?

Comment: I think you can only do it with sites that offer an API like what YouTube does with their chromeless player...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JW Player - http://www.longtailvideo.com/ - it's an open source flash/html5 video player with a large plugin library and good API

Comment: Will the JW Player really allow me to reskin Dailymotion, Metacafe, Vimeo, Viddler, etc videos? I just heard there maybe be restrictions on some of those sites which prevent developers from reskinning.

Comment: I've just googled 'JW Player Dailymotion' and it looks like technically you can. You'll have to look into licensing issues yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question when looking for the same thing. I ended up using Vimeo since it has a [chromeless option](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011183028-Embedding-background-videos) and a [javascript api](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk) that can let you build your own controls, etc. (Full disclosure: I used to work at Vimeo.)